# My website is showing Index of/ ... after editing

Tags: html, static, indexof

After coding,I uploaded the html and css codes-the site is a STATIC SITE. At first everything was perfect.

I edited it by uploading a new html and css code with different file names to replace the former while deleting the former and after refreshing the page, I saw INDEX OF/.

To be honest I don't remember the former file names. I called my hosting company and instructed them to reset my domain address in their server to make it look like am starting afresh, which they did and I uploaded the NEW files again, but all to no avail.

I need help, I don't know where I went wrong, the site has been like that since 25/2/2017. Attached is the screen shot of what am trying to explain.[the site appearance when viewed with a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCDCN.jpg)

I hope this explains better and also meets the Stackoverflow standard, thanks.

Comment: You mean directory listing?

Comment: may be you changed your index page name .

Comment: make sure you have a file called "index.html" or "index.php"

Comment: Can you include some kind of image or other indication as to what exactly your seeing?  Also please include the contents of the INDEX OF /  page so that we can rule out certain problems...... and welcome to stack overflow.  Dont forget to read this tutorial:  [ask]  -- its full of great stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of the following:

1. your home page named 'index.html'
2. put it in your root folder not in any sub folder
3. your domain pointing to the root folder of your website.

I mean to put index.html file in your website root folder not in the hosting root folder

**the third option** : when you are configuring new domain name and hosting service you have to link the domain with the folder which contain the website 
ex: if you uploaded a folder name 'mywebsite' you have to edit the settings of the domain to point to this folder.

**you may need to contact the customer support of your hosting provider to handle this**

Comment: Please can you explain your third point more maybe with an example.  And for the second option, I hope you're referring to the CGi folder inside the  PUBLIC_HTML folder under File Manager

Comment: the first step worked, that is, I changed the home page from home.html to index.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you have the index.html file uploaded in the correct location? It sounds like you are looking at the webserver filebrowser?

It looks something like this?
[image]

Comment: Yes, this is similar to want happens. I have uploaded my own case in the edited version of my post. Please do well to check it for me, thanks